# Crop function BitBlt(...)

Tags: c++, winapi, crop, bitblt

I want to create a crop function in an existing engine. This is what I already have:

```
bool Bitmap::Crop(RECT cropArea)
{
BITMAP bm;
GetObject(m_Handle, sizeof(bm), &bm);

HDC hSrc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
SelectObject(hSrc, m_Handle);

HDC hNew = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hNew, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight);
HBITMAP hOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hNew, hBmp);

BitBlt(hNew, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hSrc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

SelectObject(hNew, hOld);

DeleteDC(hSrc);
DeleteDC(hNew);

DeleteObject(m_Handle);

m_Handle = hBmp;
}
```

I want it to just copy the whole image to a new HBITMAP and replace the old with it. So I know that it works. After that it is just playing with the BitBlt parameters.

m_Handle is a HBITMAP of the class Bitmap.

The result of this code is just a black screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never create a compatible bitmap from a 'fresh' memory DC.
Unless that is you WANT to create a 1bpp bitmap - the default bitmap selected in a new memory DC is a 1x1 1bpp bitmap - so any compatible bitmap you create will match that.
Which does tend to result in all black output.

Your color bitmap in in hSrc, so use *that* dc to make the new bitmap.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for helping me.
The function works perfectly now.

```
bool Bitmap::Crop(RECT cropArea)
{
HDC hSrc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
SelectObject(hSrc, m_Handle);

HDC hNew = CreateCompatibleDC(hSrc);
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hSrc, cropArea.right - cropArea.left, cropArea.bottom - cropArea.top); 
HBITMAP hOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hNew, hBmp);

bool retVal = (BitBlt(hNew, 0, 0, cropArea.right - cropArea.left, cropArea.bottom - cropArea.top, hSrc, cropArea.left, cropArea.top, SRCCOPY))?true:false;

SelectObject(hNew, hOld);

DeleteDC(hSrc);
DeleteDC(hNew);

DeleteObject(m_Handle);

m_Handle = hBmp;

return retVal;
}
```

Comment: on the line `bool retVal = (BoolBlt(...))?true:false;`, it can be shortened to `bool retVal = BoolBlt(...);`

Answer (score 2):

Two small changes:

```
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hNew, cropArea.right - cropArea.left, cropArea.bottom - cropArea.top); 

BitBlt(hNew, 0, 0, cropArea.right - cropArea.left, cropArea.bottom - cropArea.top, hSrc, cropArea.left, cropArea.top, SRCCOPY);
```

You might want a little more checking to make sure the requested area falls within the size of the original bitmap.

Comment: Hmm, does not work. I think it has something to do with my creation of the HDC's.

Comment: The DC creation looks OK to me. You should check the return values of everything, especially the `SelectObject`s.

Comment: What should `hNew` be?

Comment: @Acidic that was in the question.

Comment: Oh, I have a stupid question: Can I use `CreateCompatibleBitmap((HDC)hBitmap, ...)`?

Comment: @Acidic no you can't.

Comment: @MarkRansom one final question which will help me so much... where does he get `m_Handle` from in the question?

Comment: @Acidic `m_Handle` is a member of his `Bitmap` class, which holds a handle to the current bitmap. How it gets initialized is outside the scope of the question.